# escape alarm() process timeout with nohup or setsid?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, system

I have a monitoring application, Zabbix agent, that allows me to run arbitrary commands/scripts and grab the return value. The agent is configured with a timeout and any command that exceeds the timeout will be killed.

For every command that is run, it first sets the timeout via [alarm(timeout)](https://github.com/yangtong/zabbix-2.0.5/blob/master/src/libs/zbxexec/execute.c#L392) and then forks the [agent process](https://github.com/yangtong/zabbix-2.0.5/blob/master/src/libs/zbxexec/execute.c#L136-182) before running the command in a new shell via `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL)`.

I have an awkward scenario that i can't adjust the agents config timeout to be greater than 2 seconds but the command i need to run will take 10-30 seconds.

So i was wondering if anyone knows some way that i can specify a command that when run can escape the timeout and run till completion. I was trying `nohup` or `setsid` thinking it wouldn't inherit the timeout set in parent but it is still killed for some reason.

Here is my example.. the agent expects `1` to be returned within it's timeout so i start my long running command in subshell and echo `1` immediately to appease it. The `/opt/scripts/test/long_running.sh` still gets killed though. I was hoping that running with nohup and in a subshell that it would escape the timeout.

`UserParameter=my.test.cmd,nohup sh -c "(/opt/scripts/test/long_running.sh $1 &); echo 1"`

Thanks for reading.

fLo

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but `nohup` typically squelches the output, so `echo 1` might not be reaching its destination. Try something like `echo 1; nohup sh -c "/opt/scripts/test/long_running.sh $1"`. I also don't think there's a need for `&` since there's no parallelism here.

Comment: thanks.. confirmed working with this command `echo 1;nohup sh -c "sleep 10; touch /tmp/10sec_timer" >&/dev/null&`. The `/tmp/` file is created after 10 seconds even though timeout is set to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nohup` typically squelches the output and prints something else, so the server might be seeing `Redirecting output to nohup.out` instead of the expected `1`.

Try something like

```
echo 1; nohup sh -c "/opt/scripts/test/long_running.sh $1" >& /dev/null
```